# How to ask a question about computer hardware (spesific part) to know its name and functionality?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Recently, I asked this question: [What is a name of this port? And for what purpose can it be used?](https://superuser.com/questions/709739/what-is-a-name-of-this-port-and-for-what-purpose-can-be-used)

I also provided a picture and its the best thing to tell what I am asking about. However, the question marked as off-topic.

I am really confused because I can't edit the question content to make it on topic, can you please help me in this context.

Thanks

Comment: The big problem with these is that you can't search for them. How is your question "What is this port?" ever going to be useful for any other person than you, who posted it? It's the same type of question as "What's this font?" or "What movie is this picture from?" etc.

Comment: I knew, but how we can ask it? is there any trick?

Comment: With regard to those specific hardware identification questions, I would have first looked up the manual of your laptop. Generally you could [ask how to identify an unknown part](http://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer) and make it canonical. Or you describe it as clearly as possible so it can be searched, e.g. "What's the trapezoid-like port on my Dell SomethingBlah laptop?".

Comment: This is one of those things that is better for chat if its something completely exotic. Even if its a good standalone question, if its *really* an unknown component, there may be a lot of questions over its nature and placement, and you can always ask a question later, based off that feedback. This should also let you search optimise it, to an extent.